# How to create admin pages in Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I currently have a simple Flask application that authenticates registered users with `flask_login` and the `@login_required` decorator. So certain pages are accessible only to registered users.
However, I want to create another layer of authentication where only admin users have access to the admin dashboard and admin login pages.

Here is my views.py file.

```
from flask import (render_template, flash, url_for, redirect)
from models import (db, app, User)
from forms import (RegisterForm, LoginForm)
from flask_login import (LoginManager, logout_user, login_user, login_required,
                        current_user)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", title="home")

@app.route("/register", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        username = form.username.data
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
        confirm_password = form.confirm_password.data

        user = User(username, email, password, confirm_password)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Thanks for registering, {}".format(username.capitalize()))
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    return render_template("register.html", title="register",
                          form=form)

@app.route("/login", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    users = User.query.all()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and users != []:
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user.checking_password(password) and user is not None:

            login_user(user)
            flash("Thanks for logging in!")
            return redirect(url_for("profile"))

    return render_template("login.html", title="login",
                          form = form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried reusing flask_login imports by renaming them with an admin_ prefix, and applying them to an admin view function, but it didn't seem to work.

```
from flask_login import (LoginManager as AdminManager,
                         logout_user as admin_logout_user,
                         login_user as admin_login_user,
                         login_required as admin_login_required,
                         current_user as admin_user)

admin_manager = AdminManager(app)
admin_manager.login_view = "admin_login"

@admin_manager.user_loader
def load_admin(admin_id):

    return Admin.query.get(int(admin_id))
```

If anyone knows how I can do this, I'd be very grateful. 
This is a lot easier to do in Django as an admin user page is generated out of the box, so to speak.

Comment: you should check [flask-admin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin)

Comment: If you can have a look at https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, that is flask role based access control.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don’t have a separate login for admin users. Rather, you have roles on each user. So if a user has an admin role, they are able to see certain pages. Then you control access to specific routes using flask-user and the [@roles_required decorator](http://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authorization.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried flask-user several times, and was able to run the basic app example. However, when it came to integrating it into my own application, it didn't work, and I personally find it overly complicated. It also pushes me to a default login page that uses bootstrap. So not very customizable in my opinion.

Comment: Just so you know, you can adjust the endpoint that’s loaded after login with USER_AFTER_LOGIN_ENDPOINT. If you don’t want to use a library, then I guess you’ll have to roll your own, with all the pluses and minuses that brings.